# Run Multiple requests of single thread group concurently

Tags: performance, jmeter

I want to simulate a scenario in which a page contains multiple requests for differ data. All runs concurrently. I created a Thread Group with all those requests and ran it for 10 users(Threads) in 0sec ramp up time. But in this Test Plan all users starts concurrent but they all process requests in sequential way i.e.(always completes first request then starts 2nd,then third,so on).

I want that all requests of each user starts at same time then completes according to their response time (Like if 3rd  takes less time than first then it should complete before 1st and 2nd). I have tried **Synchronize time**.

Comment: If you tried with the synchronize timer, what is the result? Does it not work as you expected? what is the actual behavior? share the screenshot of synchronize timer

Comment: Actually synchronize timer holds the threads not the requests. Output is like if we group **synchronize timer** by 10, no. of threads in **Thread Group** is 10 and Thread Group has 3 requests , then any one from 10 users(Threads) will start first. Output in view result table is like first request of all 10 threads, then 2nd request of all 10 threads and then 3rd.... @Naveen

Comment: well, that is the expected behaviour with Synchorize Timer. It stops the threads in order to reach the number you specified and once reached, all will be released at the same time. If you want all request to be executed without WAITING, then there is NO option as of now. you can follow the alternatives mentioned by Dmitri.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible at the moment, the relevant enhancement is being tracked as [Bug 53159](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53159)

In the mean time you have 2 options:

1. Use different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to kick off the requests. If you need to synchronize the requests you can use i.e. [Inter-Thread Communication plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/).
2. Develop some custom code using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or even create your custom sampler, see [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) for details on how this can be done.